# Process.Start() arguments does not take effect

Tags: c#, cmd

I have a code here in C#, the function of this is to generate a list of files in a folder:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "dir /B /S *.* > D:\\tempf.txt");
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\test";
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

This will just run cmd on `C:\test` and the arguments are not executed. Is there something missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `/c` argument to say "execute the rest as a command":

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe",
    "/c dir /B /S *.* > D:\\tempf.txt");
```

From the help for CMD:

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
```